# Using different controllers for different directories with the High Voltage in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, high-voltage

I'm trying to create some static pages in Rails and using the [High Voltage gem](https://github.com/thoughtbot/high_voltage) for this purpose.

What I want is to have custom URLs for different subsets of my pages. I also want to override the default High Voltage controller in order to use different layouts for different pages.

So that, say, http://example.com/about will render the about.html.erb view in the `view/pages` folder.
But http://example.com/promo/1 will render the 1.html.erb page in the `view/pages/promo` folder.

I've disabled the default routes in high_voltage.rb:

```
HighVoltage.configure do |config|
  config.routes = false
end
```

And then added a router that redirects all URLs with the `promo` path to the promo controller:

```
get "/promo/*id" => 'promo#show', as: :promo, format: false
```

But now my PromoController looks for view files in the `/views/pages` folder. How do I tell it to render views from `/views/pages/promo` folder instead?